# Solr - Error adding document with multivalued field

Tags: python, rest, solr, sunburnt

Schema:

```
<field name="tags" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Document:

```
document = {
    "id":123, 
    "title":"this is title", 
    "description":"this is desc", 
    "tags":["beach", "luxury", "RTW"]
}
```

Error:

```
<title>Error 400 ERROR: [doc=20] Error adding field \'tags\'=\'[beach, luxury, RTW]\'</title>
```

I tried REST, python module solrpy & sunburnt but gives the same error.

Comment: Useful just to see a documented way of adding a multi-value field using Sunburnt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved! It seems something was wrong with my solr schema.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what was wrong with it?